# Guice and Servlet pooling

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, dependency-injection, guice

I'm planning to start using Guice to implement DI in my webapplication project.

Looks like Guice only supports Singleton servlets or new-instance-per-request servlets. Is there a way to use a pool of servlets like regular JavaEE?

Also, does having a pool of servlets have any advantage over just creating an instance for each request. Why to even pool servlets... they seem to be quite light weight to instantiate?

Does it matter if servlet instantiation code is heavy? If I have a stateless servlet could I just forget pooling and create one per request?

Should all servlets ideally be completely stateless (not even initialisation parameters)?

Comment: In Guice, every servlet (and filter) is [required](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ServletModule#the-binding-language) to be a singleton.

Comment: I remember Java ee used to use a pool of servlets and multiplex the requests. Isn't it done anymore?

Comment: I haven't done much Java EE stuff without Guice so I can't really say.  But with Guice servlets are singletons and that's all there is to it.